# i can't access a variable in method .then() using axios

Tags: vue.js

When I try to retrieve data from `axios.get()` in `.then()`, I can't access the variable in order to put the data in.  The array, `experiences`, stays empty.

```js
     var app = new Vue({  

       el:'#app',
       data:{  
           message:' hi dear',                   
           experiences: [] 
       },                                  
       methods: {
        getExperiences: function(){
                   
            axios.get('http://localhost:8000/getexperiences')
                  .then( response => {                      
                      this.experiences = response.data;
                  })        
                  .catch(error => {
                     console.log('Erreur : ' , error);
                  })                                  
          }

       },
       mounted:function(){
           this.getExperiences();
       }
      });
```

Comment: You question is not clear, what is it exactly the problem? response.data is empty?

Comment: try to `console.log(response.data)`, how does it look like?

Comment: Non the response.data is full with data from the database the problem is when i try to put tresponse.data in the array experiences i find it exmpty

Comment: Your code works just fine as it is: https://jsfiddle.net/acdcjunior/wh5vxt8s/2/